# Error in parsing text file

Tags: c#, parsing, lines

Guys, I have an error with my code and i do not understand why, here's my code:

```
private void Parsing_String(string filename)
    {
        int outValue;
        int[][] number = new int[26][];
        List<Row> list = new List<Row>(); 

        //StreamReader freader = File.OpenText(filename);

        var parsed = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(line => line.Split(' ')
                .Where(IsInteger)
                .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                .ToArray())
            .ToArray();

        foreach (String str in File.ReadLines(filename))
        {
            String[] strCols = str.Split(' ');

            /*for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                number[i] = new int[strCols.Length];
                for (int j = 0; j < strCols.Length; j++)
                {
                    number[i][j] = int.TryParse(strCols[j].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0;
                    listBox2.Items.Add(number[i][j]);
                }
            }*/


            list.Add(new Row()
            {
                Column1 = int.TryParse(strCols[0].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0,
                Column2 = int.TryParse(strCols[1].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0,
                Column3 = int.TryParse(strCols[2].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0,
                Column4 = int.TryParse(strCols[3].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0,
                Column5 = int.TryParse(strCols[4].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0,
                Column6 = int.TryParse(strCols[5].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0,
            });

        }

        dg.ItemsSource = list;


        label3.Content = number[1][0];
        label4.Content = number[0][1];
        int kali = number[0][0] * number[0][1];
        label2.Content = kali;
    }

    static bool IsInteger(string possibleInt)
    {
        int k;
        return int.TryParse(possibleInt, out k) ? k : 0;        
    }


    public class Row
    {
        public int Column1 { get; set; }
        public int Column2 { get; set; }
        public int Column3 { get; set; }
        public int Column4 { get; set; }
        public int Column5 { get; set; }
        public int Column6 { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

}
    // Here The Text File Sample
        10192 20351 30473 40499 50449 60234 
        10192 20207 30206 40203 50205 60226 
        10192 20252 30312 40376 50334 60252 
        10192 20271 30332 40405 50209 60234

can someone show me what i am doing wrong?

what i'm wanting to do is, i have a text file containing a number, i want to parse it, and put each number in an array so i can access it easily. Is my code effective enough?

thanks, alot for a suggestion.

Comment: If you have an error with your code, why not share it? What is an example file you're trying to parse? "i have a text file contain with number" doesn't help us. If it's a parsing problem, then we need to know what you expect the file to look like.
Edit: OK, now i see the commented line where you say you get the error. Comments generally go above a line, not on the same line (80 character limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is easier without the array initialization (skip this answer if you're doing this as an exercise to using arrays in C#).

```
var parsed = File.ReadLines("SO.txt")
                 .Select(line => line.Split(' ') 
                                     .Select(MyIntegerParse)  // pick out each item as an int
                                     .ToArray())  // get array of ints 
                 .ToArray();  // return as int[][]


....

static int MyIntegerParse(string possibleInt)
{
     int i;
     return int.TryParse(possibleInt, out i) ? i : 0;
}
```

Comment: what kind of array will it be? could it int[row][column]? is it will read line by line? and last can it use the tryparse like i do?

Comment: @Reza:  What kind of array?  `int[][]` (so yes, it could be).  `ReadLines` does read line by line so it's no change from your code.  Will update with a `TryParse` implementation

Comment: nothing change? i think it's changed all? there no need for for each?

Comment: No need for a foreach.  The `Select` will do the iteration for you.

Comment: @Austin Salonen: nice code, I wanted to keep it simple, without LINQ, but ofcourse this is a much better solution :)

Comment: there's an error there, the out value seems wrong, the error says, cannot implicitly convert type int to bool.

Comment: You sure it matches what's in my answer?

Comment: sure, like this "return int.TryParse(possibleInt, out i) ? i :0;"

Comment: You may need to post the full code (preferably in your question to get the formatting).

Comment: already post the full code of mine. and dont frget about the substring because i need to delete the 2 unique code in front of each number. I'm getting understand the code that u make

Comment: @Reza:  Thanks for posting your code.  You should see a difference between my `var parsed = ...` line and yours.  Also note that `IsInteger` was removed and replaced with `MyIntegerParse` with different bodies.  The name `IsInteger` implies a boolean result so I changed it.

Comment: thanks, i already saw your code and change the myintegerparse but it nothing changed, the error is still the same, it think in your "var parsed=..." it doesnt matter because in my code, filename is where i load the text file?

Comment: @Reza:  Based on the code you posted, there is a significant difference between your assignment of `parsed` and mine...  For instance, I have no `Where`.

Comment: @Austin Salonen: thanks alot. 1. more question, if i want to access the number its all in parsed? so i just called it like parsed[0][1]?

Comment: You would use it just like any other array so `parsed[0][1]` will access the first row, second column.

Comment: yes, thanks. why if put the substring in here return int.TryParse(possibleInt.Substring(2), out i) ? i : 0 is error with startIndex cannot be larger than length of string?

Comment: @Reza:  That may be better suited as another question here.

Answer (score 3):

Your main mistake seems to be this:

```
int[][] number = new int[26][];
```

this only instantiates an array of arrays, not the nested arrays itself, so when you write

```
number[i][j] = ...
```

`number[i]` returns null, and calling indexer on a null is a NullReferenceException!

**Edit:**
What you should write is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
  number[i] = new int[strCols.Length];
  for (int j = 0; j < strCols.Length; j++)
  {
      //...
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry i'm new to programming, so i confused. can you give an example for my case? if you want of course.

Comment: No. The analysis is right but the allocations should happen _outside_ the foreach.

Comment: now in "number[i][j] = int.TryParse(strCols[j].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0;" i've got "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string"

Comment: @Henk Holterman. What do you mean? do you want to explain more? when i put it outside the for each, i can't access my text file line by line.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: yeah, you're right, I didn't see that foreach there! But if the array is not needed outside of the loop (it seems like that from this piece of code), the declaration should be moved INSIDE the foreach... So it all depends!

Comment: i think the array must be placed outside the for each? because it's a waste if put inside the for each, i edit the code so there's a sample of text file. which is 26 rows at most. and i want to read it line by line and parse it number to put in array so i can access it easily.